# Multiple validation base on radiobutton selection using jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, plugins, input

This is slight advance and beyond my basic jQuery knowledge.

This is my form:
http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/E5CRU/

Question 1:
Has 3 radiobuttons, if user select 'other', the 'other' input field would need to be validated (on load this field is disabled).
If the user selects 'school', the 'school' question shows up which consist of 2 parts that are required, school type + government or non-government.

Question 2:
I'm validation a telephone field, but I would like to allow the user to enter spaces, how do i exclude spaces in my input field?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1** : could you consider using a **jquery validation plugin** to do this and all the other stuff you want ? Here is a [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) and the [doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

Yet, you could do it with specific jquery stuff if you really didn't want to use the jquery validation plugin.

**[edit]** this is done in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/E5CRU/6/

**Answer 2** : you could use a jquery **masked input plugin** to make your inputs more user-friendly. Here is a [demo](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo) and here is the [doc](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). Btw, there are other masked input plugin if you don't like this one (meio mask...)

**[edit]** you can also use the jquery [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function to remove spaces

Regards,

Max

Comment: Hi Max, I am using the jQuery validation plugin already, please have a look at my fiddle link above. But there's some additional features in that plugin which I'm not too familiar with and not too sure how to write custom methods.